# should an angular service query method emit an error if it finds nothing

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Suppose I design a service with a method `getProducts`

And I use it like this

```
this.service.getProducts('someProduct').subscribe(product => {},
err => {});
```

should the service emit an error if `'someProduct'` doesn't exist ?

or should it just normally emit `null`.

Comment: It depends on if in your application not having a product is an error state or not

Comment: since the HTTP angular service emits an error if the response has a 404 code, I was wondering if I should  use the same behavior for my service that relies on HTTP service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I wouldn't throw an error. For the 404 handling, I'd use the catch operator, for example:

```
this.service.getProducts('someProduct')
.catch( err => {
        if (err.status ===404){
          console.log(`Product ${someProduct} not found`) ;
          return Observable.of()}    // empty observable
      })
.subscribe(product => {},
           err => {});
```